# Issue with $mail->Body in the PHPMailer

Tags: php, email

a beginner here.

I have already checked the forum to find out answers but I was not successful, other questions were specifically on some parts of PHPMailer but mine is more general. So I hope no one will mark my question as duplicate as I am in learning curve.

I am working on a PHP project. How it works is that the user goes to the page and writes some comments in a form (a text editor) and clicks on the send button. I am able to receive his message in my email. I have set the password and host empty for obvious reasons but later it will be my real email with my own domain.

Problem is 2 problems here:

- I do not want to send a static body with $mail->Body, but I want the program to take the user's message, name and email address and send that message to my email.
- When the email is received by me, I can not see the name and email of the sender which means the program is not able to get the email and name of the user from the session

Could you please give your suggestion or sample code that helps. Thank you.

```
if($_POST['mode']=='send'){

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host     = "myhost";                     // SMTP server
                                                    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->From     = "my email";
    $mail->port     = '26';                             // can also change to 465
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username= "my email"; 
    $mail->Password = "my password"; 

    $mail->AddAddress("my email");

    $Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_fname']);    //this code is not getting the name and email
    $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_email']);

    $mail->Subject  = "New Bug Report";
    $mail->Body     = "User Information, Name = " . $Name . " ||  Email = " . $Email; // I want to get the user's message not a static message!
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;

    if(!$mail->Send())
     {
      echo 'Message was not sent.';
      echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
    else 
    {
            $message = 'Thanks for your suggestion';
    }
 }
```

Here is the form in html:

```
<form role="form" name="Form2" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<textarea name="bug" cols="100" rows="15" id="textarea" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
<input name="mode" value="send" type="hidden">
<p style="margin-top:5px;"><input type="reset" value="Clear Text!" class="btn btn-danger">&nbsp; <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send report</button></p>
</form>
```

Comment: show us the html form

Comment: why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()` at all ?

Comment: @Dagon, I am trying to get the name and email and convert them to string so they can be send to my email. Should I delete them? By the way I am adding the html form to the above code, please review it after few minutes. Thank you very much.

Comment: if the form is correct all you need is `$mail->Body     = "User Information, Name = " . $_POST['part_fname'] . " ||  Email = " . $_POST['part_email'];`

Comment: @Dagon, html is attached now. Could you please review? Thank you.

Comment: there is no input named `part_fname` or `part_email` in the form

Comment: @Dagon, part_fname and part_email are name of 2 columns in a table in mySQL. I did not know I should use them in the form too, also don't know how to use them in the form!

Comment: nothing in the code connects to a db to retrieve anything. the `$_POST` array is populated from the form

Comment: That is why I am using below code to connect to the db and get the name and email:  $Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_fname']);    //this code is not getting the name and email
    $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['part_email']);

Comment: That code has nothing to do with db access\retrieval

Comment: @Dagon, awww I understand now, so could you please guide me how to get the $_POST from the form? I am not sure how to get the $_POST from the form, first time doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `mysql_real_escape_string` it requires a connection to mysql.

```
$Name = $_POST['part_fname'];    
$Email = $_POST['part_email'];
$message= $_POST['bug'];//add this to get the textarea value
```

then append the value to the body:

```
$mail->Body = "User Information, Name = " . $Name . " ||  Email = " . $Email;
$mail->Body .= "Message: ".$message;
```

---

If you wanted sessions

when to user logs in:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['part_fname'] = $Name;
$_SESSION['part_email'] = $Email;
```

when sending email:

```
session_start();
$Name = $_SESSION['part_fname']; 
$Email = $_SESSION['part_email']; 
$message= $_POST['bug'];
```

Comment: Hi @meda, this code works but the result in my email is like this: User Information, Name =  || Email = Message: Hi
this is a bug ... This means now it send the user message to me but not the email and name. Any suggestion please?

Comment: you need to add fields to the form, see like in dagon answer the HTML

Comment: Yes true, it will work with the field but my requirement says I should not have any field to get the name and email from user. the user is already signed in with his user name and email so there should be a way to get the email and username without asking him to input it again. Am I correct? If yes, do you have a suggestion for that? Thank you very much

Comment: By using session you mean this way: $Name = $_SESSION['part_fname'];    
$Email = $_SESSION['part_email'];
$message= $_POST['bug'];

Comment: unfortunately even though I used your suggestion of session, it is still not getting the name and email from the session!

Comment: to help you further I will need to see more, please update your question show how you store it when user logs in and when sending

Comment: Meda I found the problem, we are getting $Name = $_SESSION['part_fname']; 
$Email = $_SESSION['part_email'];  but I changed it to $Name = $_SESSION['name']; 
$Email = $_SESSION['email']; and now it is working fine. I am receiving the email with all details!!! But I do not understand why it is working? Because the name and email of session should come from the user table which has 2 columns named part_fname and part_email! Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes because you can call your session like you want you just need to make sure sure they are the same

Comment: I did not know that! I thought I should call the session by the column names in the db tables! Well it is all working fine now. Meda thank you so much for following up with me since last week, it means a lot as I am a beginner and you guys' support really helps me to move on to high levels. Good luck and see you in the future questions :)

Answer (score 1):

to the form you need to add the fields for the name and email like so:

```
<input name="part_fname" value="" type="text">
<input name="part_email" value="" type="text">
```

then alter the code:

```
$Name = $_POST['part_fname'];    
$Email = $_POST['part_email'];
$message= $_POST['bug'];// textarea value

$mail->Body = "User Information, Name = " . $Name . " ||  Email = " . $Email;
$mail->Body .= "Message: ".$message;
```

Comment: Yes true, it will work with the field but my requirement says I should not have any field to get the name and email from user. the user is already signed in with his user name and email so there should be a way to get the email and username without asking him to input it again. Am I correct? If yes, do you have a suggestion for that? Thank you very much

Comment: perhaps the user details are in A session ? how could i possibly know ?

Comment: yes, do you think we can use this:     $Name = $_SESSION['part_fname']; $Email = $_SESSION['part_email']; $message= $_POST['bug'];

Comment: yes, jsut make sure to use `session_start();` before accessing those variables

Comment: unfortunately it is still not getting the name and email from the session after using session!

Comment: add `print_r($_SESSION);` and see what is returned.

Comment: it is now working fine, I changed the above code to $Name = $_SESSION['name']; 
$Email = $_SESSION['email']; ... I was doing it wrong by using the session with the column names of the table in db while the sessions in my project were using email and name instead of part_email and part_fname. Thank you so much for your support and help :)